# Swift: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code :

```
class AppUtils: NSObject {
   static func showLoadingview (viewcontroller : UIViewController) { 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        }
    }
```

useage:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
     func getGroupAPI()
     {
         AppUtils.showLoadingview()
     }
}
```

Please help me thank you

Comment: You have to pass parameter in calling function

Comment: `showLoadingview (Self)`

Comment: thanks Mr.Bista . but  
Not able to dismiss LoadingView with this function now  here is the code :static func dismissLoadingView(viewcontroller : UIViewController) { if topMostController().isKindOfClass(UIAlertController) { viewcontroller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) } }

Comment: add this code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to the function, probably:

```
AppUtils.showLoadingview(viewcontroller: self)
```

Comment: Function is calling in UITableviewController so self is not working here

Comment: UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, it should work.

Comment: with argument viewcontroller: self is not wotking

Comment: showLoadingview (Self) its working .but not able to dismiss the loadingview

Comment: static func dismissLoadingView(viewcontroller : UIViewController) {
        
        if topMostController().isKindOfClass(UIAlertController) {
            viewcontroller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
    
    }

Comment: Not able to dismiss LoadingView with this function now .